# tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource

Tags: boot, dual-boot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNehU.jpg

```
[0.693363] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0xfed
40080-0xfed40ffd]
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
/dev/sda2: clean, 1516988/14557184 files, 46728488/58217728 blocks
welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to
try against to boot into default mode.
Give root password for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

This is happend and doesn't run normally when i turn on my computer every time after i made win10-install USB on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. How can i solve this

Comment: Try to disable tpm security on bios option and see if it will boot normal or not

Comment: The message , /dev/sda2....... is still existed. So i check '/etc/fstab' file and erase darddisk list without main harddisk. And it's solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to disable tmp security on bios option. then you can see the message like this.

```
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to
try against to boot into default mode.
Give root password for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

The message was decreased.

Second, press your root password on this screen. You can login root. And then

```
root@blahblah: vi /etc/fstab
```

Remove the line of sda2 and save.

Third, reboot!